# Problema al condicionar una variable extraida de un json_decode

Tags: php, laravel, peticiones

Bueno la cuestión es que estoy terminando de realizar una pasarela de pagos con mercado pago en desarrollo, tengo los usuarios de prueba y las credenciales de prueba asignadas, las cuales utilizo para realizar pagos ficticios... La cuestión es que una vez que realizo un pago con el usuario comprador (de prueba) y una vez aprobado no me redirecciona a la pagina que corresponde, se me cargan los datos en mi db, pero en mercado pago no se carga el pago... aqui dejo parte de mi codigo, este seria el controlador, el cual tiene sus respectivos modelos y todo funcionando bien solo que aqui no los pongo para ser mas breve..

```
CartController.php

public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $cartotal = \Cart::getTotal();
    $order = new Order();
    $order->total = $cartotal;
    $order->status= '1';
    $payment_id = $request->get('payment_id');

    $response = Http::get("https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/$payment_id" . "?access_token=APP_USR-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $response = json_decode($response);
    $estado = $response->status;

    if($estado=='approved'){//ACA ME MARCA EL ERROR :(
        $order->status= '2';
        Auth::user()->orders()->save($order);
    }
        return redirect()->route('cart.checkout')->withTitle('AQUAMANIA | CHECKOUT')->with(['order' => $order]);
}
```

Una vez que clickeo en "Volver al sitio" la opcion que otorga mercado pago al finalizar un pago me salta un error como este : **(Trying to get property 'status' of non-object)**

****EDIT =>** Pude reconocer que $response me esta devolviendo una stdClass, lo que necesitaria es poder transformar esa variable a un string para luego poder realizar el if de manera correcta, busque en los foros pero no pude resolver el problema..
Voy a dejar aqui lo que devuelve mi `$response`, lo que yo necesito en esta variable es que obtenga el valor string de 'status'

```
{
"acquirer_reconciliation": [],
"additional_info": {
    "authentication_code": null,
    "available_balance": null,
    "ip_address": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
    "items": [
        {
        "category_id": null,
        "description": null,
        "id": null,
        "picture_url": null,
        "quantity": "1",
        "title": "adorno ceramica barril chico",
        "unit_price": "86.0"
        }
     ],
     "nsu_processadora": null
},
"authorization_code": "1234567",
"binary_mode": false,
"brand_id": null,
"call_for_authorize_id": null,
"captured": true,
"card": {
    "cardholder": {
        "identification": {
            "number": "12345678",
            "type": "DNI"
        },
        "name": "APRO"
    },
    "date_created": "2021-10-24T17:37:48.000-04:00",
    "date_last_updated": "2021-10-24T17:37:48.000-04:00",
    "expiration_month": 11,
    "expiration_year": 2025,
    "first_six_digits": "503175",
    "id": null,
    "last_four_digits": "0604"
},
"charges_details": [],
"collector_id": 1002191120,
"corporation_id": null,
"counter_currency": null,
"coupon_amount": 0,
"currency_id": "ARS",
"date_approved": "2021-10-24T17:37:49.000-04:00",
"date_created": "2021-10-24T17:37:48.000-04:00",
"date_last_updated": "2021-10-24T17:37:49.000-04:00",
"date_of_expiration": null,
"deduction_schema": null,
"description": "adorno de algun material",
"differential_pricing_id": null,
"external_reference": null,
"fee_details": [
    {
        "amount": 3.53,
        "fee_payer": "collector",
        "type": "mercadopago_fee"
    }
],
"id": 17742836346,
"installments": 1,
"integrator_id": null,
"issuer_id": "3",
"live_mode": true,
"marketplace_owner": null,
"merchant_account_id": null,
"merchant_number": null,
"metadata": [],
"money_release_date": "2021-11-11T17:37:49.000-04:00",
"money_release_schema": null,
"notification_url": null,
"operation_type": "regular_payment",
"order": {
    "id": "3473021935",
    "type": "mercadopago"
},
"payer": {
    "email": "test_user_8675874577@testuser.com",
    "entity_type": null,
    "first_name": null,
    "id": "1002191371",
    "identification": {
        "number": "236757657614",
        "type": "CUIL"
    },
    "last_name": null,
    "operator_id": null,
    "phone": {
        "area_code": null,
        "extension": null,
        "number": null
    },
    "type": null
},
"payment_method_id": "master",
"payment_type_id": "credit_card",
"platform_id": null,
"point_of_interaction": {
    "business_info": {
        "sub_unit": "checkout_pro",
        "unit": "online_payments"
    },
    "type": "UNSPECIFIED"
},
"pos_id": null,
"processing_mode": "aggregator",
"refunds": [],
"shipping_amount": 0,
"sponsor_id": null,
"statement_descriptor": "MERPAGO",
"status": "approved",//SOLO NECESITO ESTA VARIABLE
"status_detail": "accredited",
"store_id": null,
"taxes_amount": 0,
"transaction_amount": 86,
"transaction_amount_refunded": 0,
"transaction_details": {
    "acquirer_reference": null,
    "external_resource_url": null,
    "financial_institution": null,
    "installment_amount": 86,
    "net_received_amount": 82.47,
    "overpaid_amount": 0,
    "payable_deferral_period": null,
    "payment_method_reference_id": "1234567",
    "total_paid_amount": 86
}   }//(cierra cadena)
```

`Este es el codigo de mercado pago en mi view.blade.php:`

```
@php

require base_path('vendor/autoload.php');

MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(config('services.mercadopago.token'));


$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
if(\Cart::getTotalQuantity()>0)
{
    foreach ($cartCollection as $product)
    {
        $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
        $item->title = $product->name;
        $item->quantity = $product->quantity;
        $item->unit_price = $product->price;
        $products[] = $item;
    }
$preference->back_urls = array(
"success" =>  route('cart.checkout'),
"failure" => "http://www.tu-sitio/failure",
"pending" => "http://www.tu-sitio/pending"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";

$preference->items = $products;
$preference->save();
}
@endphp
```

aca dejo tambien por si acaso mi ruta "cart.checkout" donde redirige una vez que la prueba fue aprobada:

```
Route::get('/checkout', [CartController::class, 'checkout'])->name('cart.checkout');
```

Comment: `json_decode($response, 1);`, intenta enviando (true - 1) en tu json_decode

Comment: Hola! gracias por responder! lo que seria en la variable response? -> $response = json_decode($response, 1);     asi?

Comment: Si, exactamente asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comunidad ya resolvi el problema, no era la variable el problema si no la ruta que estaba utilizando para enviar los parametros, luego de volver a realizarlo algunas veces note que el redirect no estaba realizando lo que yo queria, ademas la ruta pertenecia a cart la cual no me estaba recibiendo los parametros que yo necesitaba.
En sintesis, realice otra ruta con sus respectivas funciones, es decir, dividi la que tenia que en la pregunta se llama "checkout" y esa unicamente me obtiene el total de la compra y crea una orden, luego de ahi retorno a la vista "pay" donde recibo la orden y ahi realizo la peticion response get y me pudo funcionar correctamente! Para no borrar la pregunta quise clarificar mi error y por eso esta expliacion